# How can I change the product image path?

Tags: product, php, image, core

I would like to add a custom folder when magento creates the path for a product image. If image name is `image.jpg` the path will be `../media/catalog/product/i/m/image.jpg`. What I need is `../media/catalog/product/i/m/CUSTOM_FOLDER/image.jpg`.

Basically I need to find the `.php` that create this image path when the product is created and edit it.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand the aim behind the type of URL but if you can clear some more, then may be we can help you in different way?

Answer (score 2):

I think everything happens in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage`.

Look for the line

```
$fileName       = $dispretionPath . DS . $fileName;
```

where `dispretionPath` is `/i/m` and $fileName is `image.jpg` in the example you gave.  Try to insert something betweeen them.

You may also need to modify some code below that line.

Comment: I'll try and give you a feedback.

Comment: It didn't work. Have you tried it yourself? Anyways, I needed this because my images are been overriding when they have the same name. However it was not by Magento's fault but MAGMI image processor.

Comment: I haven't tried this. I just poked a bit in the code to see where the file is uploaded. But I have a feeling that Magmi does it differently, so even if you change the way the image path is stored you will probably still get issues.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm already talking with dweeves, MAGMI developer. By the way, I tried your awnser with MAGMI and also directly in Magento.

Comment: I will dig deeper when I will find some time and maybe I will come up with a better answer.